# Opening a folder directory through a hyperlink in a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to set the text of a label so the user can click on it and open the directory it links to.

```
self.labFolder.setText("<a href={}>Folder:</a>".format(r'C:\Users\bob\Desktop'))
```

The above displays a blue underlined label and the cursor changes to the hand as expected, but onclick does not result in the opening of the directory.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: add `self.labFolder.setOpenExternalLinks(True)`

Comment: `setOpenExternalLinks(True)` is set within qtDesigner

Comment: 1. If you do not provide information it is impossible to know what you did and what you need to do, so you must always provide a [mre], on the other hand change "\" with "/". 2) That the answer is written in C++ does not imply that it is not the solution since in the end the root is Qt whose methods have the same name in the different programming languages